# Custom UItabBarItem with green color

Tags: objective-c, ios

i would like to put a green image to my Tabbar button ( item). Can i do this or it's forbidden by Apple ?

Comment: Since Apple allows you to specify an image for the bar button, you are perfectly free to specify a green one. :)

Comment: @Jenox, tab bar images are really just transparency masks, coloration is done via the UIAppearance API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not forbidden by Apple, it is encouraged since iOS5 with the UIAppearance protocol.  I recommend reviewing the "Appearance Customization" videos from WWDC 2011 and 2012.

Comment: Can i put a background image to the selected item in my TabBar ( a green image ) ? Thanks